# Can you analyse this long weird structure please?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> A lot of people who have up until now been spending money having a good time now need to be more careful with their money.

Can you break these long sentence to its components and analyse the semantic and syntax of it please?

Comment: Commas after *spending money* and *good time* would go a long way towards clarifying the sentence.

Comment: @RonaldSole - Or a conjunction such as _and_ or _while_ between “money” and “having” might help as well. The original is not very well written; I’d prefer: _Many people who have been spending money while having a good time need to be more careful with their money now_.

Comment: @J.R. I'd prefer it too!

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people
who have 
up until now
been spending money
having a good time
now need to be more careful with their money.

Syntax is correct. The sentence means:
Up until now a lot of people had enough money. So they could afford kind of a luxurious lifestyle.
Now times are harder, they earn less money, or things have simply become more expensive, so they have to think twice whether they should buy something.